# RVM settings lost after every logout

Tags: rvm

I installed ruby, rails and gemsets using RVM on ubuntu as instructed on :
    http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:rubygems

Now the problem is that everytime I reboot machine and open console, my RVM and rails settings are lost:
when I try "rails server" - rails is not found and all gems are lost too. I need to install rails and install other gems like heroku again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sourcing $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm into your shell in its .profile or whatever setup?

That would be the first thing to check.

Add this line:

```
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
rvm --default use 1.9.3
```