# RVM 'not found' after successful usage and a few days later

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I installed RVM a few days ago, which worked perfectly. A few days later (now, after a few reboots I guess), it's like it's not installed, shell says `rvm not found` although I can see it all in my `~/.rvm` folder, and there is also a `scripts` folder into that.

I tried rerunning the install script over it, to no result (said it upgraded something, no difference). I tried the command for reloading rvm into new shell sessions. I've also had a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976861/rvm-settings-lost-after-every-logout), to no help.

What am I missing here?

(I'm on Ubuntu Natty)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would guess your `PATH` is not setup to include `~/.rvm` or `~/.rvm/bin` check if

```
echo $PATH
```

includes it. If not you will have to add somthing like

```
 PATH=$PATH:~/.rvm/bin
```

to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: So instead of following `user$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile` from the install guide, I should've directed it to `~/.bashrc` instead, is that correct?

Comment: You may try that. It's curious though because if you put that line in your `bash_profile` then it should work. It may be something else after all.

Comment: I had to look up the difference between the files. See: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html