# Why can't I change my Ruby version using RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am currently trying to switch my default version of Ruby from 1.9.3 to 1.9.2-p280.

I ran these in my console:

1. `sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm`
2. `rvm install 1.9.2-p290`
3. `rvm --default use 1.9.2-p290`
4. `ruby -v`

The output of step 4 is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show the output of `rvm list` ? And FYI, the best and right way to install `rvm` is just to follow [official doc](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/). In fact, the site says "Please use the install process(es) from this site only, as this is the only supported installation types and methods."

Comment: please do not use the Ubuntu package, it is broken, follow this instructions to fix your installation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the same session where you invoke: `rvm --default use 1.9.2-p290` and `ruby -v`?

Please take a look at the answer here for detailed explanation: [Why do I need to use "rvm use default" after opening new terminal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026754/why-do-i-need-to-use-rvm-use-default-after-opening-new-terminal-window)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that "ruby 1.9.3p0" is the default that installs from the Ubuntu packages.  Run:

```
which ruby
```

and that will tell you for sure.  Where RVM installs its Rubies depends on whether you chose the "system" or "user" installation.  But everything may already be working, just reload your shell by opening another terminal.

To make sure this is the problem, run:

```
env | grep RUB
```

you should see two environmental variables, `MY_RUBY_HOME` and `RUBY_VERSION`.  If you don't see them, then the RVM installer failed to put them in for your shell.   If we know what shell you are using, we can help.